# KOMA-Script line above and below chapter title

Tags: formatting, chapters, koma-script

I'm using KOMA-Script and I want to add a line above and below the chapter title. So the upper line should be between the "Chapter" and the title. I did this with

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{headings=chapterprefix}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%  Adding lines above and below the chapter head
%
%%%%%%%% BEFORE HEADING
% \appto\chapterheadstartvskip{%
%   {%
%       \noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}\par%
%   }%
% }   
%%%%%%%% AFTER HEADING
\preto\chapterheadendvskip{%
    {%  
        \noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}\par%
    }%
}
%%%%%%%% BETWEEN LABEL AND HEADING
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadmidvskip}{%
    {%
        \vspace{-.3\baselineskip}%
        \par\noindent%
        \noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}
    }%
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\blindtext

\chapter*{Test the second}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

The problem is with the `\chapter*`. It doesn't have the line above. If I include the first part of the code in the example that is now commented, I get the line above `\chapter*`, but also a third line above `\chapter`.

Is there anyway to define the `\chapterheadstartvskip` separately for `chapter` and `chapter*`? Or is there anything like `\isThisAChapterWithAsteriks`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With KOMA-Script version 3.19a (current on CTAN and in TL2015 und MiKTeX2.9) or newer you can redefine `\chapterlineswithprefixformat` to insert the line if option `headings=chapterprefix` is set:

```
\documentclass[
  headings=chapterprefix
]{scrbook}
%\providecommand*\Ifstr{\ifstr}% needed up to and including KOMA-Script version 3.27, see https://komascript.de/faq_deprecatedif

\newcommand\titlerule[1][1pt]{\rule{\textwidth}{#1}}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[innerskip=0pt]{chapter}

\renewcommand\chapterlineswithprefixformat[3]{%
  #2\nobreak%
  \Ifstr{#2}{}{}{\kern-\dp\strutbox}%
  \titlerule\par\nobreak%
  #3%
  \par\nobreak\titlerule%
}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\blindtext

\chapter*{Test the second}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

---

If the lines should be also there without `headings=chapterprefix` you also have to redefine `\chapterlinesformat`:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapterlinesformat[3]{%
  \titlerule\par\nobreak%
  \@hangfrom{#2}{#3}%
  \par\nobreak\titlerule%
}
\makeatother
```