# overfull hbox on chapters with line above/below chapter title using KOMA-script

Tags: koma-script, boxes

I would like to add `\linewidth`-sized lines above and below my chapter titles (similar to borders above/below the 'paragraph' in MS Word)

I tried the following, which somewhat approximates the desired look (not perfect, and I don't really understand the `\kern-.75\ht\strutbox` stuff:

```
\documentclass[
    draft,
    parskip=full,
]{scrreprt}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\chapterlinesformat}[3]{%
\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{%
\raggedchapter%
\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{.6pt}%
\par\@hangfrom{#2}{#3}%
\par\kern-.75\ht\strutbox\rule{\linewidth}{.6pt}%
}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{test}
\end{document}
```

However, this causes overfull hboxes on every chapter title (and makes it difficult to see if I have *actual* overfull hboxes), even though the lines do not extend past the width of the text area.

I also tried the solution in [KOMA-Script line above and below chapter title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273343/koma-script-line-above-and-below-chapter-title) (lowermost part of the accepted answer), however the lines are very far from the text and the overfull hbox issue persists (if only on the lower rule).

Comment: I can tell you *why* it happens. It's go to do with `parskip` being `full`. What I guess komascript is doing is adding a rule or something at the end of each paragraph to make sure it has at least one em left at the end (though I haven't checked). If you add `\par` after your `parbox` the overfull line is solved (but the spacing is off). I'd be inclined just to live with it: the output (once draft mode is off) is fine.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, “living with it” makes it very difficult to find real issues later.

Comment: You need to add a \par after the \parbox, to avoid that the wrong \parfillskip is used.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer adding `\par` shifts the entire thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a \par at the end or a wrong parfillskip will be used. To avoid the shift you can locally set parskip to zero:

```
\documentclass[
    draft,
    parskip=full,
]{scrreprt}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\chapterlinesformat}[3]{%
\parskip=0pt
\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{.6pt}%
\par\@hangfrom{#2}{#3}%
\par\kern-.75\ht\strutbox
\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{.6pt}%
\par
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{test}

bbbb

\chapter{test test test test test some text text text text test xtt }

bbbb\par abc

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm getting inconsistent spacing from the top of my textarea and the top line. Sometimes even negative... (in the real-world document)

Comment: Having found a workaround for the inconsistent spacing (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/476356/understanding-stretchy-negative-vertical-space-above-framed-chapter-titles) I will accept this as it was the earlier answer.

Answer (score 2):

From the KOMA-Script documentation of option `parskip=full`:

> one line vertical space between paragraphs; there must be at least 1 em free space in
>   the last line of a paragraph

`\chapterlinesformat` is called inside a group with `\parskip` set to 0pt and `\parfillskip` set to `0pt plus 1fil`. But this group is followed by a `\par` command using your `parskip=full` setting and there is no 1em free space after the `\parbox` ...

If you do not need the 1em free space in the last line of paragraphs, you could use `parskip=full-`:

```
\documentclass[
    draft,
    parskip=full-,% <- changed
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{showframe}% to show the page layout
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\chapterlinesformat}[3]{%
\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{%
\raggedchapter%
\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{.6pt}%
\par\@hangfrom{#2}{#3}%
\par\kern-.75\ht\strutbox\rule{\linewidth}{.6pt}%
}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{test}
\lipsum[1-2]
\chapter{test test test test test some text text text text long text }
\lipsum[3-4]
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

But note there is really no white space in the last line of the first paragraph.

You could also use `\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-1em\relax][l]{...}` or better `\makebox[.65\linewidth][l]{...}` (ensures that it works for `parskip=+` and `parskip=full*`, too):

```
\documentclass[
    draft,
    parskip=full
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{showframe}% to show the page layout
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\chapterlinesformat}[3]{%
  \makebox[.65\linewidth][l]{% <- added
    \parbox[t]{\linewidth}{%
      \raggedchapter
      \noindent\rule{\linewidth}{.6pt}%
      \par\@hangfrom{#2}{#3}%
      \par\kern-.75\ht\strutbox\rule{\linewidth}{.6pt}%
    }%
  }% <- added
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\chapter{test}
\lipsum[1-2]
\chapter{test test test test test some text text text text long text}
\lipsum[3-4]
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]