# Underline chapter title and number in scrbook

Tags: scrbook

I am trying to find a way to draw a line below the chapter title including the chapter number. The solution proposed here [KOMA-Script line above and below chapter title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273343/koma-script-line-above-and-below-chapter-title) except that in my case the chapter number is in the margin. The solution should work with `latexmk` and `pdflatexmk`.

So is there an easy way to extend the line to include the chapter number?

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[default, scale=.90]{opensans} % police Open Sans

%% Chapter number in the margin
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  \llap{\thechapter\autodot\enskip}%
}
 
%% Draw a rule of size \textwidth
%% Modification of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273343/koma-script-line-above-and-below-chapter-title
\newcommand\titlerule[1][1pt]{\rule{\textwidth}{#1}}
\renewcommand\chapterlineswithprefixformat[3]{%
  #2\nobreak%
  \Ifstr{#2}{}{}{\kern-\dp\strutbox}%
  \titlerule\par\nobreak%
  #3%
  \par\nobreak\titlerule%
}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapterlinesformat[3]{%
  \@hangfrom{#2}{#3}%
  \par\nobreak\titlerule%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can measure the width of the chapter number and make the rule longer, but sticking to the left.

```
\newcommand\titlerule[1][1pt]{%
  \settowidth{\dimen0}{\thechapter\enspace}%
  \hspace*{-\dimen0}\rule{\dimexpr\textwidth+\dimen0}{#1}%
}
```

Complete example (two chapter headers in the same page just to make a smaller picture).

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% no longer necessary
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[default, scale=.90]{opensans} % police Open Sans

%% Chapter number in the margin
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  \llap{\thechapter\autodot\enskip}%
}
 
%% Draw a rule of size \textwidth
%% Modification of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273343/koma-script-line-above-and-below-chapter-title
\newcommand\titlerule[1][1pt]{%
  \settowidth{\dimen0}{\thechapter\enspace}%
  \hspace*{-\dimen0}\rule{\dimexpr\textwidth+\dimen0}{#1}%
}
\renewcommand\chapterlineswithprefixformat[3]{%
  #2\nobreak%
  \Ifstr{#2}{}{}{\kern-\dp\strutbox}%
  \titlerule\par\nobreak%
  #3%
  \par\nobreak\titlerule%
}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapterlinesformat[3]{%
  \@hangfrom{#2}{#3}%
  \par\nobreak\titlerule%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}

\begingroup\let\cleardoublepage\relax

\setcounter{chapter}{10}

\chapter{Test}

\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I was looking for. As I expected Latex wizards are able to solve the problem I was struggling with for hours.